# Data can't be fetched in ReactJS from ASP.NET webService

Tags: reactjs, web-services, fetch, localhost, webmethod

I'm using ReactJS with functional components for my front-end trying to fetch data from the ASP.NET WebService,

**SomeComponent.jsx**

```
 const URL = 'http://localhost:63579/WebService.asmx/ProductList'
 const productList = () => {
    fetch(URL) 
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        settingResults(data);
      });
  };
```

The WebService webmethods are working - checked ✔ all data received from the SQL.

**Edit this is the Error**-

**Error:**

[image]

**The output string from Webservice**:

`<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Vitamin C","CategoryName":"Vitamins","Price":10,"Stock":268,"ProductDescription":"","ProductOverview":"","ProductImage":"https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1052/1052788.png"}</string>`

Comment: This is issue in the service side not in react. You should modify your config to allow cors..

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your web service web.config, and it should work

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235751/discussion-between-extrasun-and-rabeeh-mohammed).